# Pharmaceutics PhD in the USA where most time is spent in home country

Tags: phd, united-states, part-time

Can apply for a PhD in pharmaceutics or clinical pharmacy in the USA? I already have a master's degree from Egypt. I was told that it is possible to enroll in a PhD program there and travel to the USA for only 1-3 months per year and continue your work from your country. Is this true? If yes how can I apply? Will it be funded?

Comment: What you ask is unusual. Part time is likely a problem as is funding. In the US, the degree is probably called pharmacology. You can search for universities that have such doctoral programs. I guess (only guess) that clinical programs might be rare outside medical schools. Good luck.

Comment: Who told you this and can you ask them for more information? The general answer is "no" but it is possible there are specific programs that I wouldn't describe as you have but may come close.

Comment: The answer is of course "Yes, you can apply". But in truth, most institutions will consider your request a non-starter. Why would a university hire someone who is hardly ever there?